# allocating EKEventStore throws warnings

Tags: swift, objective-c, eventkit, ekeventstore, ekeventkit

When creating EKEventStore object, I do get the following lines in the console:

```
XXX: countOfStores: 0, countOfAccounts: 0
[change-history] Change history operation performed with no stores
[core] "Exceeded the maximum number of connections (2) to accountsd: 3 connections open. Consider switching to +[ACAccountStore defaultStore]"
```

The EKEventStore is created only once.

swift:

```
let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
```

objc:

```
_store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

Should the logs be ignored? If yes, how to get rid of them? And what does it have to do with switching to ACAccountStore?

Comment: I get several errors for the same line of code. With the build target any 10.15, I get the first two lines listed in this question. With build target at 12.0 I get different ones. One another laptop, Xcode can run this code and have the event store actually work, no problem with either target version.